# The button of added view does not work 

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I push test2ViewController in Test1ViewController.m,

```
Test2ViewController *test2ViewController = [[Test2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:test2ViewController animated:YES];
```

in Test2ViewController.m, I insert a subview test3ViewController,

```
Test3ViewController *test3ViewController = [[Test3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test3ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:test3ViewController.view];
```

my question, I wanna push a new view (test4ViewController) in test3ViewController, but the button action in test3ViewController.view does not work

```
-(IBAction) goButtonAction:(id) sender {
    Test4ViewController *test4ViewController = [[Test4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test4ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test4ViewController animated:YES];
}
```

It seem that the test3ViewController is not in navigation flow, how can I push a new view on a insert view?

Answer (score 0):

test3ViewController was never added to the stack for the navigationController. If you want to push test4ViewController, then you will have to either do it from test2ViewController, or use the setViewControlers:animated: method of UINavigationController to add test3ViewController to the stack:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:test2ViewController.navigationController.viewControllers];
[array addObject:test3ViewController];
[test2ViewController.navigationController setViewControllers:array animated:NO];
[test2ViewController.navigationController popToViewController:test3ViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this. But it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the IBAction is getting called?